# Creating Pie Chart in Openpyxl, but it is only grabbing half of the data

Tags: python, excel, data-visualization, openpyxl

I am trying to create a piechart to be inserted into a specific excel sheet from my data using openpyxl. However, when I input all the regular fields it is only grabbing half of the data. Can anyone else see why?

Data is from specific cells in the excel sheet.

The Data labels are in Row 4 and Columns 13 through 16

The Data is in row 5 and data is in columns 13 and 16

It seems to only grab Row 4 and 5 in columns 13 and 14

Here is my code:

```
      pie=PieChart()
      labels = Reference(ws, min_col=13,max_col=16, min_row=4, max_row=4)
      data = Reference(ws, min_col=13, max_col=16,min_row=5, max_row=5)
      pie.add_data(data,titles_from_data=True)
      pie.set_categories(labels)
      pie.height=7
      pie.width=9
      pie.title="$ Amount"
      ws.add_chart(pie,'M8')
```

documentation on charts found [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/pie.html)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the odd solutions is the labels and data has to be listed vertically. Also, it requires that the Data column min_row start at the data title.